# How can i fix my code so a float be iterable?

Tags: python

```
for spamicities in sorted(map(lambda body: self.word_spamicity(body),re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  body).split())
                                ,key=lambda x: abs(0.5 - x),reverse=True)[0:38]:
 hamicities = map(lambda x: 1-x, spamicities)
```

spamicities is a float and i got an error `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

How can i fix my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fail:

```
spamicities = 1.0
hamicities = map(lambda x: 1-x, spamicities)
```

`map` only works on lists. So if you want to use `map`, put your float into a list:

```
spamicities = [1.0]
hamicities = map(lambda x: 1-x, spamicities)  # returns [0.0]
```

A more conventional example (multiple list values):

```
spamicities = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 20.0]
hamicities = map(lambda x: 1-x, spamicities)  # returns [0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -19.0]
```

> i updated my question with the complete code

Get rid of your for-loop, as its iterating over your list returned by `sorted` and giving you one float at a time. You want the entire list like so:

```
spamicities = sorted(map(lambda body: self.word_spamicity(body),re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  body).split()),key=lambda x: abs(0.5 - x),reverse=True)[0:38]
hamicities = map(lambda x: 1-x, spamicities)
```

Comment: but the problem that spamicities also uses map

Comment: It can't possibly be both a `map` object and a `float`.